# Ngrok: Expose Database in Docker Container

Tags: docker, elixir, ngrok

I have a web application built with Elixir that uses a Postgres database in a docker container (https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).

I need to expose the web interface (running on port 4000) and the database in the docker container.

I tried adding this to my configuration files:

```
tunnels:
  api:
    addr: 4000
    proto: http
  db:
    addr: 5432
    proto: tcp
```

Then in my Elixir `config/dev.exs` I add this under the database configuration:

```
... 
hostname: "TCP_URL_GIVEN_BY_NGRROK"
```

When I attempt to start the application, it says failure to connect to the database.

The docker command that I used is:

`docker run --name phoenix-pg -e POSTRGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d postgres`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JustinWood I just made and edit.

Comment: Show your docker command, please

Comment: @cricket_007 made an edit.

Comment: You've not forwarded your host port to point at the database port in the container with a `-p 5432:5432`, for example